# What if we want to use mouseClick Method many times with different implementation

Tags: java, user-interface, interaction

How we can use same method (same paramater and return type) with different implementation 
in other word , in java Gui i want to use mouseClick method in many different way in one class , how this could be possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would implement different MouseListeners and add these to each component you want different mouseClick behavior in.

Edit: I added an example below.

```
public void example() {

    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            /* your code here, what should happen when the mouse clicked the panel */
        }
    });

    JTable table1 = new JTable();
    table1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            /* your code here, what should happen when the mouse clicked the table */
        }
    });
}
```

Here I used `new MouseAdapter()` [more here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html) instead of `new MouseListener()`, which implements MouseListener because this allows you to only implement a single method of the MouseListener interface.

Comment: can you give me simple example pls ?

Comment: Sure, I added an example above.

Comment: No worries. If this answered your question, be sure to mark it as the solution. :)